# Cordova Browser Platform Documentation

Tags: cordova, browser

I was just looking around about the cordova Browser platform on [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/03/04/cordova-browser-4.1.0.html) and [here](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform), and seems really interesting, I'd like to use it. Tho I see the [github repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser), I couldn't seem to find the documentation. Nor is there documentation on the [Cordova site](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/). Does anyone know where to find this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think it's a simple answer of... it doesn't exist yet. :(

Comment: Oh well. Thanks mate